# GCP VM shut itself down, won't restart

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

Bit panicky here because I can't troubleshoot the error on a production site and it appears to be completely down.

GCP - Compute Engine VM - N1-standard on the US-West-3C zone running a Bitnami Multisite Wordpress deployment

About 2 hours ago my VM stopped responding (as far as I could tell with monitoring tools) and I was unable to SSH into it or connect in any way. I've experienced this occasionally in the past so my process was to grab a snapshot and restart the VM. I did manage to get the snapshot, however it stopped the VM by itself and I'm now stuck where I can't restart the VM.

The error I'm getting is:

> Failed to start name-of-vm: A n1-standard-1 VM instance is currently unavailable in the us-west3-c zone. Alternatively, you can try your request again with a different VM hardware configuration or at a later time. For more information, see the troubleshooting documentation.

I tried changing my configuration (it used to be a custom VM) but that didn't do anything.

Searching for similar errors I've found threads about certain Zones running out of resources, but as far as I can tell this error doesn't specifically say 'run out of resources' and the status of the US-West-3C zone is fine. I can't imagine it would run out in a way where it can't even start a measly n1 vm.

Unfortunately due to some mismanagement this project isn't umbrella'd in our Google Workspace/Organization so I can't request technical support for it.

Any assistance or help pointing to some resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Don't lose the snapshot. 2) The zone is out of resources for that machine size. Try selecting a larger instance size (several sizes larger) so that a different rack is selected. You can always resize it smaller later once you have recovered. 3) I will guess the instance shutdown due to a lack of free disk space. Resize the boot disk larger. Use the serial console to confirm the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I ended up spinning up a new instance based on the snapshot in a different zone with a slightly higher configuration and changed my DNS to point to the new IP.

Immediate fire is put out, but I'm still confused about root cause. The disk utilization was only sitting at around 50%, I had actually just a few weeks ago done some clean up to clear up most of that space. (a good chunk of it was just apt/cache filling up). Not sure if I would find logs to give me much info about the situation.

Answer (score 0):

`currently unavailable` in a specific zone would also mean that the zone `run out of resources` for the certain machine type.

You can try to restore the snapshot you had created on a different machine type `e2-standard` or `n2-standard` machine type configuration